# Git: simple deployment, how can I avoid 'pull not possible because you have unmerged files'

Tags: git, deployment

What I've got is a local repository and 2 remote repositories (a `bare` called bare and a non-bare called dev).

What I'm trying to achieve is a simple deployment so that when I push to the bare repository the dev repository pulls the changes.

I am using a post-receive hook on the bare repository which simply does:-

```
cd (path-to-dev-repo)
unset GIT_DIR
git reset --hard HEAD # This is my failed attempt at stopping the merge conflicts
git pull origin master
```

When I make changes to my local repository and push them to the bare when the dev trys to pull it gives me things like:-

```
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in application/01_sql_schema.sql
```

However the only file changes I have made are to the local files - I don't understand why the changes can't be merged automatically when they have only been changed in one place.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit: Alternative Possible Solution**

Would it be better to have 2 bare repositories and checkout the development one to the desired folder from a hook?

Comment: have you tried `unset GIT_DIR` at the top of your hook?

Comment: @DietrichEpp Apologies - `unset GIT_DIR` is in the hook above the `git reset --h...` - I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a repo for the deployed version?

Just use `GIT_DIR=path/to/app git checkout -f` to checkout the files from the bare repo to the app location and avoid problems like these.

Comment: Because I have zero experience with git :) that seems like a much better solution. Presumably I could also checkout a specific branch, so for example have a branch in the bare repo for staging and production and checkout all of these in my hook to their respective locations. So to release a fix would simply mean editing the production branch and pushing to the bare repository - is that a sensible way to do it? (I'm essentially developing alone, with a couple of other people contrubuting v occationally)

Answer (score 0):

Try stashing the changes and then popping them afterwards:

```
cd (path-to-dev-repo)
unset GIT_DIR
git stash
git pull origin master
git stash pop
```

Comment: The 'stash pop' does it's own merge and thus the same problem is likely to occur.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same problem with this.